# Not getting SMS_DELIEVERD Responce when sending sms via SmsManager

Tags: android

I am sending a text message using `SmsManager` but i am using a wrong numbers to send `sms`. like i am in `pakistan` where country code is +92 and i am using numbers like these. +92 **** i am trying different combinations of 4 digits after country code.sometimes `SmsManager` is sending the message and i am getting both `SMS_SENT` AND `SMS_DELIEVERD` Response But sometimes i am getting just `SMS_SENT` response. I am showing user `progressDialog` when he sends `sms` and canceling the `progressDialog` on `SMS_DELEIVERD`. So when i am not getting `SMS_DELIEVERD` response `progressDialog` spins infinitely. How to handle that? and why am i not getting `SMS_DELEIVERD` ??

-tHANKS

Comment: So if the number is wrong.The message will not be delivered.Then logically you should not get an `SMS_DELIVERED` broadcast right?

Comment: Right but i shouldn't but what about wait dialog i am showing to user?? in this case what tot do ??

Comment: So do it like whatsapp does.Instead of an indeterminate `progressDialog` you could use provide a countdown timer where you wait for that long to receive the `SMS_DELIVERED` broadcast.Failing which,you would then proceed usually.

Comment: No, i am showing dialog at the time of sending sms. after i get sms delieverd response, i am up to the next step.

Comment: The `SMS_DELIVERED` broadcast is not always assured,it is network  and user dependent(if user disables the **notify on delivery** setting in the sms app).Hence to make your logic work,it would be advisable not to depend on that for any purpose

Comment: So you want to say i can do the next step on when i receive sms sent response ?? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70290/discussion-between-droidekas-and-usman-riaz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SMS_DELIVERED` broadcast is not a guarantee.It is based on the user settings and the network.So you would be better off not keeping your logic dependent on the this broadcast.You could use a timer as a pseudo-alternative.